# RhinoMocks: how to test if method was called when using PartialMock

Tags: c#, rhino-mocks

I have a clas that is something like this

```
public class MyClass
{
  public virtual string MethodA(Command cmd)
  { //some code here}
  public void MethodB(SomeType obj)
  { 
     // do some work
     MethodA(command);
   }

}
```

I mocked MyClass as PartialMock (`mocks.PartialMock<MyClass>`) and I setup expectation for MethodA

```
var cmd = new Command(); 
//set the cmd to expected state
Expect.Call(MyClass.MethodA(cmd)).Repeat.Once();
```

Problem is that MethodB calls actual implementation of MethodA instead of mocking it up. I must be doing something wrong (not very experienced with RhinoMocks). How do I force it to mock MetdhodA?

Here is the actual code:

```
  var cmd = new SetBaseProductCoInsuranceCommand();
            cmd.BaseProduct = planBaseProduct;
            var insuredType = mocks.DynamicMock<InsuredType>();
            Expect.Call(insuredType.Code).Return(InsuredTypeCode.AllInsureds);
            cmd.Values.Add(new SetBaseProductCoInsuranceCommand.CoInsuranceValues()
                               {
                                   CoInsurancePercent = 0,
                                   InsuredType = insuredType,
                                   PolicySupplierType = ppProvider
                               });

            Expect.Call(() => service.SetCoInsurancePercentages(cmd)).Repeat.Once();

            mocks.ReplayAll();

            //act
            service.DefaultCoInsurancesFor(planBaseProduct);

            //assert
            service.AssertWasCalled(x => x.SetCoInsurancePercentages(cmd),x=>x.Repeat.Once());
```

Answer (score 2):

I've tried to reproduce this issue, and it seems to work fine, what is different between my test code (below) and yours?

```
public class MyClass
{
    public virtual string MethodA(object cmd)
    {
        return "implementation";
    }

    public string MethodB(object obj)
    {
        // do some work
        return MethodA(obj);
    }

}

[TestFixture]
public class MyClassTests
{
    [Test]
    public void MockTest()
    {
        var myClassMock = MockRepository.GenerateMock<MyClass>();
        myClassMock.Expect(x => x.MethodA("x")).Return("mock");
        Assert.AreEqual("mock", myClassMock.MethodB("x"));
        myClassMock.VerifyAllExpectations();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here seems to be that while in your comments you said [PartialMock](http://ayende.com/Wiki/Default.aspx?Page=Rhino+Mocks+Partial+Mocks), but in your code sample you use [DynamicMock](http://ayende.com/Wiki/Rhino+Mocks+Introduction.ashx). I believe this is the source of your issues, as they behave differently.